# "you wouldn't want to invite someone that you knew wouldn't want to come."

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions, will-would

***If you were having a party, you wouldn't want to invite someone that you knew wouldn't want to come.***

- Is this sentence *'that you knew wouldn't want to come.'* also hypothetical OR does it refer to the past tense? As there is a past simple 'knew' and 'would' that's why I assume so.
- is 'would' = 'will' in this part of the sentence?

Comment: There is nothing in the context here to lead us to believe any kind of past is being discussed. It's all hypothetical.

Comment: I think the word "hypothetical" isn't helpful when considering the status of *...that you knew wouldn't want to come* as opposed to *...who **didn't** want to come.* Not to mention which, it's irrelevant that the element ***that you knew*** happens to be included, since the entire utterance would be *completely meaningless* if the addressee *didn't* know that (it's *entailed* by the utterance, not just implied).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *"If you were having a party, you wouldn't want to invite someone who didn't want to come."*  OR *"If you were having a party, you wouldn't want to invite someone who **doesn't*** want to come." Would the latter be correct? or is there a rule to use the past form in the main clause?

Comment: Your OR version is clumsy, because you're mixing "present" *(**doesn't**)* and "not present" *(**were, wouldn't**)* in the same utterance. Note that the "backshifting" here is entirely optional; it would be fine to say *If you **are** having a party you **don't** want to invite someone who **doesn't** want to come.* But if you ***are / were*** gonna "backshift" (which we usually do in this context), it's better to be consistent (as per the ***first*** version in your comment immediately above this).

Answer (score -1):

It is a hypothetical.  The word "would" could not be replaced with the word "will" unless you changed the sentence to something like this:

*If you are having a party, you won't want to invite someone that you know won't want to come.*

Of course, the meaning isn't the same, although the gist of it is.  Note:  *will not* is replaced here by the contraction *won't*.

Comment: The word "would [not]" could obviously be replaced with the word "**didn't**". And I don't believe that change would make the slightest difference to the meaning, so it's ***not*** in any meaningful sense a "hypothetical" reference - except insofar as the utterance starts with *You **wouldn't** want to invite...* as a "polite circumlocution" for *You **don't** want to... = **You shouldn't...***